# Show an alert view when current location is near pin location

Tags: iphone, loops, annotations, location, mapkit

I've the user current loaction, and the annotation pin location.
When the user clicks on a button, the app starts to calculate the distance between the user current location and the pin location.
This is my code:

```
- (IBAction)done:(id)sender {

[Locate startUpdatingLocation];
CLLocation *current;
CLLocation *pin;
do{
    current=[[CLLocation alloc]initWithLatitude:Locate.location.coordinate.latitude longitude:Locate.location.coordinate.longitude];
    pin=[[CLLocation alloc]initWithLatitude:arrived.latitude longitude:arrived.longitude];

}while([current distanceFromLocation:pin]>1000);

}
```

The problem is, that when I click on this button (Done), it seems to enter an infinite loop and the app stops working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using an if statement, not a for loop. That loop will be executed until the user is within 1000 meters of the pin.

```
- (IBAction)done:(id)sender {

    [Locate startUpdatingLocation];
    CLLocation *current;
    CLLocation *pin;

    if ([current distanceFromLocation:pin] > 1000) {
        current = [[CLLocation alloc]initWithLatitude:Locate.location.coordinate.latitude longitude:Locate.location.coordinate.longitude];
        pin = [[CLLocation alloc]initWithLatitude:arrived.latitude longitude:arrived.longitude];
   }

}
```

I imagine that you would want to re-call this method once the user's current location has changed.